# Boostrap of Dataframe for Re-estimation

Tags: julia, resampling, dataframes.jl, dataframesmeta.jl

I have a given dataset and want to create a bootstrap (with resampling) of 10 replicates of the dataframe and have new ids assigned to them in the final dataset. Please guide me on this.

```
Random.seed!(123)
df = DataFrame(
    id = ["1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3"],
    time = [0,0.5,2,0,0.5,2,0,0.5,2],
    cmt = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    value = [0.01,0.02,0.03,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.01,0.05,0.10]
)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure that this is what you want:

```
julia> reduce(vcat, [df[rand(1:nrow(df), nrow(df)), :] for i in 1:10], source="replicate")
90×5 DataFrame
 Row │ id      time     cmt    value    replicate
     │ String  Float64  Int64  Float64  Int64
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 2           0.5      0     0.03          1
   2 │ 3           2.0      0     0.1           1
   3 │ 2           0.5      0     0.03          1
   4 │ 3           0.0      1     0.01          1
   5 │ 1           0.0      1     0.01          1
   6 │ 2           0.5      0     0.03          1
   7 │ 1           2.0      0     0.03          1
   8 │ 3           2.0      0     0.1           1
   9 │ 3           0.0      1     0.01          1
  10 │ 2           0.5      0     0.03          2
  11 │ 3           0.5      0     0.05          2
  12 │ 3           0.5      0     0.05          2
  13 │ 2           0.0      1     0.02          2
  14 │ 2           0.5      0     0.03          2
  ⋮  │   ⋮        ⋮       ⋮       ⋮         ⋮
  78 │ 2           0.5      0     0.03          9
  79 │ 3           2.0      0     0.1           9
  80 │ 1           0.0      1     0.01          9
  81 │ 1           0.5      0     0.02          9
  82 │ 1           0.5      0     0.02         10
  83 │ 1           0.0      1     0.01         10
  84 │ 2           0.0      1     0.02         10
  85 │ 2           0.5      0     0.03         10
  86 │ 1           0.5      0     0.02         10
  87 │ 1           2.0      0     0.03         10
  88 │ 1           0.0      1     0.01         10
  89 │ 1           0.5      0     0.02         10
  90 │ 3           0.5      0     0.05         10
                                   63 rows omitted
```

It creates is a data frame, where for each unique `replicate` value you have a separate bootstrap sample of your original `df` data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, finally found what I was looking for. Let me know if there is a better way to do it.

```
df = DataFrame(
    id = ["1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3"],
    time = [0,0.5,2,0,0.5,2,0,0.5,2],
    evid = [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    dv = [missing,0.02,0.03,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.01,0.05,0.10]
)

# Sample the id column and create a vector with 3 replicates of each id
sampled_ids = vcat([sample(unique(df.id), 3) for _ in 1:3]...)

# Sample all rows of each ID using sampled_ids vector
new_df = DataFrame(id = String[], time = Float64[], evid = Int64[], new_id = Any[], dv = Vector{Union{Missing, Float64}}())

for (i, unique_id) in enumerate(sampled_ids)
    id_rows = df[df.id .== unique_id, :]
    id_rows.new_id .= i
    append!(new_df, id_rows)
end


# Print the new DataFrame
println(new_df)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?